# How can I add 3 bullet points in Graphviz on top of the arrow between two nodes?

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to create a neural network diagram using Graphviz. So basically I want to leave more space between Dropout 1 and LSTM 4 and add on top of the arrow 3 bullet points to indicate that there are more layers repeating. Also since I have in total 50 nodes I would like to leave space between the first two red nodes and the third one and adding bullet points there as well. Hope I am making myself clear.

Diagram I am trying to create I used paint to draw the spacing and the bullets

[image: Diagram I am trying to create I used paint to draw the spacing and the bullets]

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    splines=line     
    node [fixedsize=false, label=""];

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        color=white;
        node [style=solid,color=red2, shape=circle];
        x1 x2 x3;
        label = "Input layer (60,1)";
    }
        subgraph cluster_1 {
        color=white;
        node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
        a12 a22 a32;
        label = "LSTM 1 (60,1)";
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 {
        color=white;
        node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
        b12 b22 b32;
        label="Dropout 1(0.2 probability)";
    }
subgraph cluster_7 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
    c12 c22 c32;
    label="LSTM 4(60,50)";
}

subgraph cluster_8 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
    d12 d22 d32;
    label="Dropout 4(0.2 probability)";
}

subgraph cluster_9 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid,color=red2, shape=circle];
    O;
    label="Dense(1)";
}
    
        x1 -> a12;
        x1 -> a22;
        x1 -> a32;
        x2 -> a12;
        x2 -> a22;
        x2 -> a32;
        x3 -> a12;
        x3 -> a22;
        x3 -> a32;
    
        a12 -> b12;
        a12 -> b22;
        a12 -> b32; 
        a22 -> b12;
        a22 -> b22;
        a22 -> b32;
        a32 -> b12;
        a32 -> b22;
        a32 -> b32;
    
        b12 -> c12;
        b12 -> c22;
        b12 -> c32; 
        b22 -> c12;
        b22 -> c22;
        b22 -> c32;
        b32 -> c12;
        b32 -> c22;
        b32 -> c32;
    
        c12 -> d12;
        c12 -> d22;
        c12 -> d32; 
        c22 -> d12;
        c22 -> d22;
        c22 -> d32;
        c32 -> d12;
        c32 -> d22;
        c32 -> d32;
    
    
        d12 -> O
        d22 -> O
        d32 -> O

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some scafolding (invis nodes and edges)
also needed an xlabel not to bend one of the edges
and constraint on some edges to make drawing straight

e.g.:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    splines=line     
    node [fixedsize=false, label=""];

{node[shape=point color=invis] x0 a02 b02 c02 d02}

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        color=white;
        node [style=solid,color=red2, shape=circle];
        x0
        x1 x2 x3;
        label = "Input layer (60,1)";
    }
        subgraph cluster_1 {
        color=white;
        node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
        a02
        a12 a22 a32;
        label = "LSTM 1 (60,1)";
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 {
        color=white;
        node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
        b02
        b12 b22 b32;
        label="Dropout 1(0.2 probability)";
    }
subgraph cluster_7 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
    c02
    c12 c22 c32;
    label="LSTM 4(60,50)";
}

subgraph cluster_8 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid,color=blue4, shape=circle];
    d02
    d12 d22 d32;
    label="Dropout 4(0.2 probability)";
}

subgraph cluster_9 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid,color=red2, shape=circle];
    O;
    label="Dense(1)";
}

edge[minlen=2]
    {node[shape=point color=invis] 
     edge[dir=both arrowhead=tee arrowtail=tee]
    rank=same x03->x02[label=<&#x22ee;>] // is utf8 vertical ellipsis
    }
    {edge[style=invis minlen=1]
        x003[shape=none]
        x003->x03->x1
        x02->x2
        
    }
    {
     edge[dir=both arrowhead=tee arrowtail=tee]
        b02 -> c02[xlabel="..."]
    }
    //{rank=same b32 b02}
    
        x1 -> a12;
        x1 -> a22[constraint=0];
        x1 -> a32[constraint=0];
        x2 -> a12[constraint=0];
        x2 -> a22;
        x2 -> a32[constraint=0];
        x3 -> a12[constraint=0];
        x3 -> a22[constraint=0];
        x3 -> a32;
    
        a12 -> b12;
        a12 -> b22[constraint=0];
        a12 -> b32[constraint=0]; 
        a22 -> b12[constraint=0];
        a22 -> b22;
        a22 -> b32[constraint=0];
        a32 -> b12[constraint=0];
        a32 -> b22[constraint=0];
        a32 -> b32;
    
        b12 -> c12;
        b12 -> c22[constraint=0];
        b12 -> c32[constraint=0]; 
        b22 -> c12[constraint=0];
        b22 -> c22;
        b22 -> c32[constraint=0];
        b32 -> c12[constraint=0];
        b32 -> c22[constraint=0];
        b32 -> c32;
    
        c12 -> d12;
        c12 -> d22[constraint=0];
        c12 -> d32[constraint=0]; 
        c22 -> d12[constraint=0];
        c22 -> d22;
        c22 -> d32[constraint=0];
        c32 -> d12[constraint=0];
        c32 -> d22[constraint=0];
        c32 -> d32;
    
    
        d12 -> O
        d22 -> O
        d32 -> O

}
```

rendered on viz-js.com

[image]